# Memoria compartida en Ubuntu c++

Tags: c++

Trato de hacer un par de programas que trabajen con memoria compartida (Servidor y cliente) en Ubuntu, para Windows he encontrado que se puede crear memoria compartida de la siguiente manera y me funciona bien.

```
int BUF_SIZE = sizeof(Message) * 2;

string sharedName = "Global\\MyFileMappingObject";
string message = "";
HANDLE hMapFile;
hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
             INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
             NULL,                    // default security
             PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
             0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
             BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
             sharedName.c_str()       // name of mapping object
);
```

Sin embargo para Ubuntu no he encontrado la correspondencia de esta función que haga lo mismo que en Windows.

Comment: Te refieres a un espacio de memoria que pueden usar 2 programas para compartir informacion en linux?

Comment: @eyllanesc así es, un espacio de memoria que pueden usar 2 programas en linux.

Comment: Hay algo similar para Linux: [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), o los [segmentos compartidos](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget) del System V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacerlo en Ubuntu siempre puedes acceder directamente a las llamadas del API de POSIX: mmap, como sugiere Trauma.

Sin embargo, ya que estás en varias plataformas distintas, yo te sugeriría utilizar el interprocess de boost, de forma que tu código sea portable. Viene bastante bien explicado aqui:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html